# How to solve "Error: There was an error trying to save the key to disk" when enabling Bitlocker via command line?

Tags: bitlocker

When trying to initiate Bitlocker on a systemdrive from the command line an error is returned:

> ERROR: There was an error while trying to save the key to disk.

This isn't the first time I ran into this error so now I share this here because the error threw me off. There is nothing wrong with the disk/usb-drive.

Original command:

> manage-bde C: -on -StartupKey "U:\" -RecoveryKey **"F:\recoverykeys\"** -UsedSpaceOnly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Powershell auto-completes path names with the 'tab' key, which is how I typed it, manage-bde does not like it at the end of folders. You must however provide it after your drive-letter.

***Remove the trailing backslash.***

> manage-bde C: -on -StartupKey "U:\" -RecoveryKey **"F:\recoverykeys"** -UsedSpaceOnly